# Eigenvectors of multiple different observations without the need of covariance matrix?

Tags: python, math, image-processing, pca, eigenvector

Trying to recreate program mentioned [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fdca/5ecdf5fff9b5580a6bf18a813e3982693ea9.pdf)

I am currently working on a project that involves performing PCA on a covariance matrix.

It first involves turning N 250x250 (MXM) images into a (250x250)x1 matrix effectively turning every pixel into its own "feature" after doing this I then work out the average feature values denoted by X.

I then work out the difference between each image and X and store these differences in a variable Y.

This is where it becomes a little tricky in the paper described they state that they created covariance for each image and then took the means of these covariance matrices however the size of these matrices would be (250x250)x(250x250) which causes memory errors. I mentioned this to my supervisor who has recommended me to investigate decomposing an NxN matrix and then convert the eigenvectors instead, this to me makes it seem as though I can find the eigenvectors without computing the covariance matrix of each image and averaging them.

So my question is how do I work out eigenvectors without computing a covariance matrix over N samples?

I hope this makes sense, thanks for reading.

Comment: This is probably more suited for Math SE https://math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Section III, step 6 explains how a smaller matrix of size M x M can be used instead.

Comment: @NicoSchertler I did see that but I don't quite understand the process that they describe, I'll have a more detailed look at it.

Comment: The matrix entry `a(i, j)` contains the `i`-th pixel of image `j`. Your original covariance matrix `C=A A^T` can be expressed as `c(i, j) = sum_k  a(i, k) * a(j, k)`, where `k` iterates all images. Now, your modified matrix `L = A^T A` does not sum over the images but over the pixels: `l(i, j) = sum_k a(k, i) * a(k, j)`. Hence, this makes sense if you have less images than pixels in an image.

Comment: Btw, I really doubt that the proposed method gives satisfactory results. It all is a bit too random. So, don't be surprised if your implementation does not seem to work. It might not be your fault.